# how to put data into an image from sequence

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

How to put sequence (raw) data of one image into another which has different size?
Visual effect expected to be as one of `crop` method but data should come as raw data

```
...
sequence = image1.getdata()
size=(int(image1.size[0]/2),int(image1.size[1]/2))
image2 = Image.new(image1.mode, size, "black")
seq_in=[]
for i in xrange(len(sequence)):
      seq_in.append(sequence[i])
seq_out=transform_data(seq_in,size,image1.size)
image2.putdata(seq_out)
...
```

following 2 variants of transformation give different results but not as would be expected

```
transform_data(seq_in,size,size_in):

#seq_t=do_something_with_the_data(seq_in)
seq_t=seq_in

seq_out=[]
#A:
sz=size[0]*size[1]
for i in xrange(sz):
      seq_out.append((seq_t[i]))
# end A
#B:
seq_r = numpy.array(seq_t).reshape(size_in[0],size_in[1],3)

for i in xrange(size[0]):
   for j in xrange(size[1]):
      seq_out.append((seq_r[i][j][0], seq_r[i][j][1], seq_r[i][j][2]))
#end B

return seq_out
```

Comment: "not as would be expected" - would be helpful if you could explain how the results are not as you expect.

Comment: I'd expect to see in a new image a piece cropped from the original. With variant A I see a piece of the image split into two (not equal) parts combined with white stripes. In the variant B the content is not recognizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it very hard for us to figure out what you're trying to do (especially because you already told us the code you've included doesn't work). But this is how I would do a crop:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

size = image1.size
size = [i//2 for i in size]
array1 = np.asarray(image1)
array2 = array1[:size[1], :size[0]]
image2 = Image.fromarray(array2)
```

Notice that array1 has shape (y, x, 3) if image1 has size (x, y). If you need to put the values from array2 into an existing image I believe the easiest way is:

```
image2.fromstring(array2.tostring())
```

Also in your code `sequence` is already a "sequence" (or it is iterable if you want to be technical) so you don't need to create a seq_in, but if you really want to have sequence as a list, you can do `seq_in = list(sequence)`

I still don't quite understand the problem you're having but maybe this example will help clear things up:

```
image1 = Image.open("img1.jpg")
array1 = np.asarray(image1)
array2 = np.fft.fftn(array1)
array2_uint = (np.log(np.abs(array2)) * 14).astype('uint8')
image2 = Image.fromarray(array2_uint)
array3 = np.fft.ifftn(array2).astype('uint8')
image3 = Image.fromarray(array3)
```

Image1

[image: image1]

Image2

[image: image2]

Image3

[image: image3]

As you can see both array2_uint and array3 get correctly converted to images. Can you try and explain the problem you're having, maybe update the code in your question to include an example or the wrong output if you're getting the wrong output.

Comment: Bago, thanks for your reply. The issue is not with a list on input, it is with the list on output. Empirically I've found the way to save image data after transformation is A pointed above or B. Would I be able to get array2 = transform(array1) and image2 = Image.fromarray(array2) that would be great. Unfortunately it doesn't go through even for a 'dry run' when the size is kept the same. For example, having the transform as data=numpy.fft.fftn(array1, s=None, axes=None) array2=numpy.fft.ifftn(data, s=None, axes=None) and returning array2 does not results in the picture, variants A,B do

Comment: axes permutation b/w the image and data array might be an issue too

Comment: I'm trying to transform an image content. A simple example as given above: `data=numpy.fft.fftn(array1, s=None, axes=None) array2=numpy.fft.ifftn(data, s=None, axes=None)`. Generally speaking in this case input!=output but somehow 'magics behind the scene' gives me the input picture = output picture when I transform the array into a list and use `image.putdata(my_list)` if I keep the size the same(!), if I following your advise return an array and try to save in into my image as `image = Image.fromarray(array2)`, the image looks not as original.

Comment: when `s != None` the size may change and here the issue came my A and B variants return different results and not what is expected. But they do not resist size change even without transformation. Yours variant works well when the size changes but no data transformation. But just to crop a piece of an image one can use crop method.

Comment: `.astype('uint8')` made the job :). Now it works even with size change. Thanks, Bago